I am uncertain as to which perspective is correct; however, I believe my reasoning is sound.
Topic:
Form a set of positive integers $S$ by seeding $S$ with two positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a \neq b$. Then if $x$ and $y$ are in $S$ where $x \neq y$, and $g$ is the greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$, include $z$ in $S$ where $z=\frac xg+\frac yg$.
For example if we start with $a = 6$ and $b = 10$, then $8$ is also in $S$ since $\gcd(6, 10) = 2$, where $\gcd(6, 10)$ is the greatest common divisor of $6$ and $10$, and $8＝\frac62+\frac{10}{2}＝3+5$.
Is it possible to seed S with distinct positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $S$ is a finite set?
I believe the set $S$ must be infinite, because after selecting values for a and $b$, there is a high probability of generating two coprime numbers $x$ and $y$, forming $\gcd(x, y)$. This will continuously generate new numbers, thus making the set $S$ infinite.
However, one person suggests that when a and b are powers of $2$, they will cause the set $S$ to be a finite set. Even if there are cases where $\gcd(x, y) = 1$, the newly generated numbers can still be expressed in the form of an odd number multiplied by a power of $2$, and will not jump out of this range. Since the number of odd numbers less than a certain fixed value is finite, and the powers of $2$ are also finite, because the generated numbers will not increase infinitely, the number of elements in $S$ must be finite.

"high probability" doesn't seem relevant here, since you aren't asked if it is likely that the choice of $(a,b)$ leads to a finite or infinite set, just what's possible.  The power of $2$ example seems more promising.

But is it right?  The power of $2$ argument, I mean.  If $(a,b)=(2,4)$ then $\gcd(a,b)=2$ so we have $\frac 22+\frac 42=3\in S$, right?  Which means $7\in S$ since we can choose $(4,3)$, and then$11\in S$  and so on.

Titles are important for attracting people to your question. This title tell us nothing about the nature of the question, so people clicking on it risk wasting their time, and people who can help won't know and maybe won't help. You are asking people to volunteer their time to help. Help people help you.

Hint: Show that once you get to 2 coprime integers, we can generate infinitely many. $\quad$ Hint: Show that if $\gcd(x, y) > 1$, then $ \gcd( x, \frac{x + y } { \gcd(x , y ) } )  < \gcd(x, y)$.
